# Directline bot echo back inputted message after implementing token instead of secret?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1x1g.png) I have developed own API which generates and refreshes token using directline api. The problem is after that when I integrated token instead of Secret in above code, my bot replies the answer correctly but also echo back the input which is being provided. There is no such implementation done in code and with secret and emulator all works fine.

```
(function () {

    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.0/css/fabric.min.css">');
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css">');
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chatbot.css">');


    var chatIsVisible = false;

    $(function () {

        $(".botwrapper").toggle();

      

        $('<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChromeMinimize minimizeIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>').appendTo(".wc-header");

        $("#botbutton").click(function () {
            chatIsVisible = true;
            $("#botbutton").toggle("fade", function () {
                $("#BotChatGoesHere").toggle("fade", function () {
                    $(".chatbot .wc-shellinput").focus();
                });
            });

        });

        $(".wc-header .minimizeIcon").click(function () {
            $("#BotChatGoesHere").toggle("fade", function () { $("#botbutton").toggle("fade"); chatIsVisible = false; });

        });

        setTimeout(showBot, 3000);
        setInterval(shakeBot, 10000);


        function showBot() {
            $("#botbutton").toggle("fade").effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow");
        }

        function shakeBot() {

            if (!chatIsVisible) {
                $("#botbutton").effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow");
            }
        }


    });

    const params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);

    const user = {
        id: params['userid'] || 'userid',
        name: params['username'] || 'User'
    };

    const bot = {
        id: params['botid'] || 'SAM',
        name: params['botname'] || 'SAM'
    };

    const speechOptions = {
        speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({ locale: 'de-DE', subscriptionKey: '' }),
        speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({
            gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
            subscriptionKey: '',
            voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (de-DE, Stefan, Apollo)'
        })
    };

    window['botchatDebug'] = params['debug'] && params['debug'] === 'true';

    function ConnectWebBotChat() {
        let headers = {
        };
        if (botConnection !== null) {
            // for refresh token
            headers = {
                old_token: TokenResult.token,
                user_id: TokenResult.userId
            };
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:64102/api/DLToken",
            //async: "false",
            method: "POST",
            data: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: headers,
            success: function (result, status, jqXHR) {
                TokenResult = result;
                botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
                    domain: params['domain'],
                    secret: result.token,
                    token: result.token,
                    webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true'
                });
                BotChat.App({
                    bot: bot,
                    resize: 'detect',
                    user: user,
                    speechOptions: speechOptions,
                    directLine: botConnection
                }, document.getElementById('BotChatGoesHere'));
                PingBotConnection(true);
                console.log("SAM Connection Refreshed : " + status);
            },
            error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("SAM Connection Refresh : " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
    function PingBotConnection(_IsFirstTime = false) {
        botConnection
            .postActivity({
                from: user,
                name: 'Connection Test',
                type: 'event',
                value: ''
            })
            .subscribe(function (id) {
                console.log('SAM Pinged OK!');
            });
        botConnection.connectionStatus$
            .subscribe(connectionStatus => {
                handleConnection(connectionStatus);
                if (!_IsFirstTime)
                    ConnectWebBotChat();
            });
    }
    function handleConnection(connectionStatus) {
        switch (connectionStatus) {
            case 0:
                console.log("SAM Uninitialized");
                break;
            case 1:
                console.log("SAM Connecting");
                break;
            case 2:
                console.log("SAM Online");
                break;
            case 3:
                console.log("SAM ExpiredToken");
                break;
            case 4:
                console.log("SAM FailedToConnect");
                break;
            case 5:
                console.log("SAM Ended");
                break;
        }
    }

    let botConnection = null;
    let TokenResult = null;
    ConnectWebBotChat();
    setInterval(() => { PingBotConnection(false); }, 1780000);

})();
```

Bot should not echo back the inputted message on use of Directline Token.

Many thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you post your bot code as well? Also, when you had added the Secret, the bot did not echo back the inputted message?

Comment: Thanks for connecting ! Yes I used the secret it works fine. I tested in Bot Channel Web Test and also at emulator it works fine too over there.

Comment: I am extremely sorry that I can't post whole bot code as due to Company policy. I got this issue after integrating the token, till then all things were working fine since last 6 months. But then requirement came to secure the secret key, hence I implemented the token for it.

Comment: @ranusharao : Please check updated js code

Comment: can you test your bot locally using [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) and see if you are able to repro the same issue ? Also, can you attach a screenshot of the emulator logs(by clicking on the echo back input message, it will display the JSON on the top panel)?

Comment: Sure I will check it, however I found something .

Direct Line will helpfully send your client a copy of every sent activity, so a common pattern is to filter incoming messages on:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS




I tried it and it worked but not sure how to integrate it in above code. I just pasted the code and displayed in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the above posted code, it looks like you are passing the token as a secret. I would recommend you just pass one not both.

[image]

Also, I would recommend you to upgrade to web chat v4 as it provides more support when it comes to customization. This [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.c.getting-started-migration) provides a detailed guide on how to migrate from Web Chat v3 to v4.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, yesterday I tried same though it has the same issue. Even after using V4 js as you mentioned too, I found that some ans are not populating. :(

Comment: Many thanks for the help, I used the v4 and now everything is working fine. However do you have idea any alternative of this https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css

Comment: Glad that your issue was resolved. The alternative to botchat.css would be cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js.